# Total differential equation with an integrating factor depending on the product $xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, differential, integrating-factor

**Description**

Show that if the quantity $$\frac{\frac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q(x,y)}{\partial x}}{yQ(x,y)-xP(x,y)}$$
is a function $g(z)$ of the product $z=xy$, then the quantity:

$$\mu=e^{\int g(z)dz}$$
is an integrating factor for the equation:
$$P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$$

---

I am certain this is a problem about total differential equations but I am not sure how to translate the first quantity into the function $g(z)$.
The equation that requires the integrating factor could be a differential of another function, which is constant. How do I pick up from there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mu$ is an integrating factor, then
$$
\frac{\partial (P\mu)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\mu+P\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial(Q\mu)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\mu+Q\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x},
$$
that implies
$$
\mu\Big(\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\Big)=(yQ-xP)\mu g,
$$
and the result is proved. Recall that
$$
\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\mu g y,
$$
by the chain rule and something analogous for $\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}$.